# How to authenticate git commands which work with remote repository and launch in the powershell script that is run from a TFS pipeline

Tags: git, powershell, tfs

I wrote a script that I expect to work when launched from pipeline and locally manually on the windows agent. It contains git commands, which works with remote repository, for example `git pull`. Local run doesn't return any errors. But run from `TFS` pipeline returns for `git pull`

```
fatal: Authentication failed for <remote_repository>
```

As I understood, git needs remote's credentials to access it. When it runs under my user account, it retrieves it somehow. But not when runs from pipeline.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add more on the `<remote_repository>` URL? Is it an HTTPS or SSH one? Is it an Azure DevOps repository? Or a GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> git needs remote's credentials to access it. When it runs under my user account, it retrieves it somehow.

First, it depends on the remote URL (HTTPS or SSH).
And second, under your user account, Git can find either your private SSH key, or your credential stored in a cache (check the output of `git config --global credential.helper`)

But for your TFS pipeline, you need to check your [Git service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#other-git-service-connection), and make sure the password used is a PAT (Personal Access Token), not your actual account password (at least, this is true for GitHub, GitLab or Bitbucket repositories).
There are dedicated BitBucket or GitHub service connection, but the idea remains the same: check your credentials there.